# How to configure TestNG testng.xml to ensure that one group runs at the end of all the other groups?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng.xml

I have multiple test groups in my test suite (a,b,c, etc).
If I have to make a group 'z' run at the end of all other groups (the list is not fixed and can grow), how do I do it through testng.xml?

TestNG documentation suggests using the below in testng.xml:

```
<test name="My suite">
  <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="z" depends-on="a  b  c" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
</test>
```

But in my case a,b,c are not fixed. There can be tens of groups which I can't explicitly list in testng.xml everytime a new group is added.

This is how my current testng.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="App tests">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="smoke"/>
                <exclude name="rest"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="apps.webdriver.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: u can create a group of groups... https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups

Answer (score 0):

I can think of "grouping" tests in terms of classes/packages. Your z group will be in a separate class while a,b,c....will be in different class.